# Use a counter in for loop to take a counting result

Tags: r

I would like to have as output this:

```
This is the text [1] from process
This is the text [2] from process
This is the text [3] from process
```

How can I make it using a for loop? What I tried:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
                  query_line<- "This is the text["+i+"]from process"
  }
```

And the error is:

```
Error in "This is the text[" + i : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?cat`:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    cat("This is the text [", i, "] from process\n")
}
#This is the text [ 1 ] from process
#This is the text [ 2 ] from process
#This is the text [ 3 ] from process
```

---

If you just want to store it in a variable, you can do the following (don't forget to initialize the storage variable in advance):

```
n <- 3
res <- character(n)
for (i in 1:n) {
   res[i] <- paste("This is the text [", i, "] from process")
}
```

Then, results are stored in `res`:

```
res
#[1] "This is the text [ 1 ] from process" "This is the text [ 2 ] from process"
#[3] "This is the text [ 3 ] from process"
```

---

However, if you really just wanted to create a character vector with that text, you could do it in a single `paste` call:

```
paste("This is the text [", 1:3, "] from process")
#[1] "This is the text [ 1 ] from process" "This is the text [ 2 ] from process"
#[3] "This is the text [ 3 ] from process"
```

Comment: I try to add the result to a variable in the for loop using this `my_sentence <-cat("This is the text [", i, "] from process\n")`. But when I type variable name my_sentence is null. Any idea if I make something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `message` function which generates diagnostic message. It is displayed in red.

```
 for (i in 1:5)
 message(paste("This is the text [",i,"] from process",sep=""))
```